# Android phone OS compatibility

Tags: android, rom

I am trying to create Android mods and I have an old HTC Magic (Froyo). Is it possible to load 4.0 into this old device? If not, what hardware needs do I have to take into account?

Comment: might be best to upgrade to gingerbread via this [linky](http://www.allroundgeek.com/2011/07/upgrade-your-htc-magic-to-android-23.html) in which there's an embedded linky to xda to get your handset up to date, relatively... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official compatibility document which details all the must-have and the nice- to-have features for running ICS. A thorough study of this should help you find everything you need.

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The one for Jelly Bean should someone come to this question looking for it is at http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd.pdf